# It is/was the best movie I have/had ever

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

suppose I am coming out of a cinema hall just after watching a film. Someone asks me, "how was the movie? I reply "oh! That was a great movie. I have/had never seen a movie like this before." 'have' or 'had': Which one should I choose?

I can also reply "oh! That was a great movie. It is/was the best movie I have/had ever seen."

Again the same problem, which one should I choose?

Answer (score 1):

To keep your tenses consistent, use *had* for the first case, as it implies that "not seeing a movie like this' is in the past.

For the second case, the first sentence refers to the movie when you watched it, not the movie in general. (Otherwise you would have used "That is a great movie"). Therefore since we are referring to the movie in one of its instances (when you watched it), the second sentence should begin with *was*. After that, *have* seems like the logical choice since this phrase *I had ever seen* is technically describing the movie, and is attributed to the word before it, hence not having its own tense.

However, this is dialogue, and the rules are loosened, particularly because people don't perform this type of analysis before speaking, therefore you are a bit more flexible in this situation.

I know I got a bit technical there; if you need clarification I'd be happy to help.

Comment: In my opinion, you are wrong - there should be **have** in both cases. You speak about yourself here and now.

Comment: It would be correct if the whole situation was in the past: _Yesterday when asked about the movie I replied that I had never seen such a good movie before._

Comment: That is a valid perspective, but in direct speech, let's say someone had a date, and was asked immediately afterwards about the date itself. He/she would say: "It was the best"

Comment: It doesn't matter **was** or **is** about the movie—it was then and is now good. Have is about **you** not the movie. And **you** are here and now, therefore being only able to **have** some attribute but not **had** it.

Comment: the was or is, I perceived, referred to the speaker's experiencing of the movie, rather than the movie as a whole, as in, this particular screening. The have is certainly about you.

Comment: In the first dialogue *had* must be used, since now you now have seen a movie so great.

Comment: My point is that was\is doesn't matter: _That was\is a great movie, I **have** never seen anything like it before._

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64112/discussion-between-confused-soul-and-mv-log).